# subunit2sql configuration for Azure database

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to setup a Azure powered database to be used by subunit2sql.
In the subunit2sql db setup steps, it is mentioned to create the schema as:

```
subunit2sql-db-manage --database-connection mysql://subunit:pass@127.0.0.1/subunit upgrade head
```

Replacing the mysql tab with mssql, and after creating a odbc SDN connection to the azure DB - I'm able to see the database.

However, subunit2sql connection always fails with the below trace. 
My understanding is that I might not be using a proper config for alchemy/python, but the messages are confusing me, as if I use isql for eg with the SDN DB info I can connect to it fine.

Command I'm running is:

```
subunit2sql-db-manage --verbose --database-connection mssql://user:'pwd'@remote_host/DB upgrade head
```

I do have the odbc config under /etc/odbcinst.ini and /etc/odbc.ini but the above fails with:
oslo_db.exception.DBError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

(sorry I cannot add subuni2sql tag here as I don't have points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing my testing. Hope it helps.

According to the `requirements.txt` of project `subunit2sql` on GitHub, the tool required Python package `SQLAlchemy`, so I refer to the SQLAlchemy [document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/mssql.html?highlight=mssql#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pymssql) support for the Microsoft SQL Server database via the pymssql driver to set the database connection with the Azure SQL Database connection string, please see below.

```
subunit2sql-db-manage --database-connection mssql+pymssql://<username>@<hostname>:<password>@<hostname>.database.windows.net:1433/<database> upgrade head
```

Note: You can find the variables `username`, `password`, `hostname` & `database` in the SQL Database connection string on Azure portal.

For connecting SQL database successfully, you need to do the steps below before running the above command.

As reference, My environment is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

1. Refering to the document [`Configure development environment for Python development`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt694094(v=sql.1).aspx) to install the required package for Python.
2. Configuring the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file, for example as below.

   ```
   [FreeTDS]
   Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
   Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
   Server={hostname}.database.windows.net
   UsageCount=1
   Port=1433
   Database={database}
   User={username}@{hostname}
   Password={password}
   TDS_Version=7.2
   client_charset=utf-8
   ```
3. Configuring the firewall settings to add the client ip, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/.

Althought I got the error information as below, successfully connected the SQL Database.

> oslo_db.exception.DBError: (pymssql.ProgrammingError) (102, "Incorrect syntax near '`'.DB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 156, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO test_metadata_new (id,`key`, value, test_id, new_test_id) SELECT tm.id, tm.key, tm.value, tm.test_id, tn.new_id FROM test_metadata tm INNER JOIN tests_new tn ON tn.id = tm.test_id']

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter! I was able to connnect to the DB using the mssql+pymssql connection type, however I then get into the same error as you've described. I verified this with the latest stable subunit2sql and also the dev build. As such I've raised an issue with them to see what they have to say.

Comment: @user3144292 Thanks for your sharing!